# Make links to external tumblr blogs not clickable from the notes section of a tumblr post

Tags: tumblr

Ive recently setup a tumblr blog for a company account. On tumblr when someone reposts or comments on a post they get shown up in the comments section, which in tumblr is called notes.

For an example see this post here : http://minimalist.co/post/49073058900/robert-downey-jr-by-greg-williams#notes - See the links to other tumblrs at the bottom (not my tumblr blog but you get the idea)

These links are all `nofollow` which is fine, but the issue im having is that some of these sites may contain adult content, and because this is a business account, it cant link to adult content.

Is there a way to remove the `href` from these links so they cant be clicked through, either doing it server side by editing the tumblr theme, or client side using JS ?

---

**UPDATE**

Ive found i can remove the notes completly by removing these lines from the theme :

```
 {block:PostNotes}
 section class="post_notes">
 <a name="notes">
 {PostNotes}
 </a>
 </section>
 {/block:PostNotes}
```

But these removes the notes feature completely, what id prefer to do is still have the notes but not allow them to be links.

---

**UPDATE 2**

This is the html used on the page

```
<li class="note reblog tumblelog_sixtensason without_commentary">
    <a rel="nofollow" class="avatar_frame" target="_blank" href="http://sixtensason.tumblr.com/" title="Sixten Sason in wonderland" sl-processed="1">
        <img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_ed56f53ce743_16.png" class="avatar " alt="">
    </a>

    <span class="action" data-post-url="http://sixtensason.tumblr.com/post/110092976968">

        <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sixtensason.tumblr.com/" class="tumblelog" title="Sixten Sason in wonderland" sl-processed="1">
            sixtensason
        </a> 

        reblogged this from 

        <a rel="nofollow" href="http://example.com" class="source_tumblelog" title="Interior design blog - LLI Design London" sl-processed="1">
            example
        </a>

    </span>

    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</li>
```

I updated the the JS to the below, but to no avail, any ideas ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('span.action a').attr('href','');
                $('li.note a').attr('href','');

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need to see your blog, or some more specific markup but there is a way to remove the href with jquery.

jQuery tends to ship along with many templates but if yours doesn't have it you just need to add a single line of code.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.post_notes a').attr('href','');
});
```

This says get all anchors inside the post_notes element and set the href to an empty string.

Checking in some of my themes I can see that there are tumblr template links which can be removed from the template they look like `href="{Permalink}"`, but I think for the postNotes block you cannot edit the href, as far as I can tell.

**EDIT:**

Or you could disable the click event:

```
$('.post_notes a').click(function(){
   return false;
});
```

Comment: The first solution is better as it completely disables the link. The latter is still focusable, right-clickable and hoverable

Comment: @bfred.it yeah I was merely demonstrating that there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: thanks @lharby - i updated implemented the above script in my updated post , but to no avail any idea why this wouldnt be working ?

Comment: @sam Can you post a link to your tumblr. I can see that the span.action has a data attribute (not the href) and the other links have classes of tumblelog and source_tumblelog so it depends which one needs disabling.

Comment: Although your code should work from what you have written. Is jQuery definitely included, maybe check the console for errors?

Comment: @lharby - thanks it seemed to be an issue with jquery  being called from a tumblr hosted repo, which is no longer live, changed it to use the google hosted version